# 'HeadersPath' is not supported for a 'framework' in library 'ios-arm64'

Tags: ios, swift, recaptcha

'HeadersPath' is not supported for a 'framework' in library 'ios-arm64'.getting that error.

'HeadersPath' is not supported for a 'framework' in library 'ios-arm64'.
I am adding the pod "RecaptchaEnterprise", "18.5.0-beta01" in my project. also add the excluded Architecture as arm64.